# How to recreate apply in scheme

Tags: function, recursion, scheme, lisp, apply

how would i create the function apply in scheme?
A my-apply function that does the same thing as it.

```
 (define (my-apply fn lst)
 (if (null? lst)
```

I'm not sure where to go from here or how to start.

Comment: what are you allowed to use?

Comment: All pure functional constructs, and map since I implemented that already

Comment: if you can use `eval`, the task is trivial ;-)

Comment: I don't think I can :(

Comment: Then I don't think you can implement `apply`.

Comment: Out of curiosity how would I do it with eval?

Comment: How do you represent functions?

Comment: That interface cannot do the same thing as `apply`; it can do the same thing as just the two-argument case of `apply`, which is a variadic function.

Answer (score 3):

I think `apply` is "more fundamental" than `eval`, so the following is cheating:

```
(define (my-apply func args)
  (eval `(,func ,@args)))
```

I don't think you can do it without `eval`.

Answer (score 1):

I created a lisp interpreter a while back and it has `eval` and macros, but it didn't have `apply`. I wondered if there was a way I could make my interpreter support `apply` so made an effort to try this. Here is my first attempt:

```
(define (my-apply proc args) 
  (eval (cons proc args)))
```

This clearly doesn't work since the function and the list of arguments gets evaluated twice. eg. `(my-apply cons '(a b))` will give you `(cons a b)` and not `(cons 'a 'b)`. I then thought that this might be a job for a macro but threw the idea away since the list of arguments are not known at macro expansion time. Procedure it needs to be so I though I could quote the list before I pass it to `eval`.

```
(define (my-apply proc args)
  (define (q v)
    (list 'quote v))
  (eval (cons proc (map q args))))
```

This actually works, but this does a lot more work than a native `apply` would do to undo the job `eval` does.

If you are not allowed to use `eval` you are truely out of luck. It cannot be done. The same goes for implementing `eval` without using `apply` since then you have no way of doing primitives.

Answer (score 0):

```
(define (my-two-arg-apply f a)
  (let ((l (length a)))
    (cond ((= l 0) (f))
          ((= l 1) (f (car a)))
          ((= l 2) (f (car a) (cadr a))
          ...
          ((= l 5) (f (car a) (cadr a) ... (caddddr a)))
          ...
          ((= l 7) (f (car a) (cadr a) ... (caddddr a)
                      (list-ref a 5) (list-ref a 6)))
          ... ;; lots more cases
          (else (error "argument passing limit exceeded")))))
```

A macro could be used to generate the large quantity of code needed.

`error` was introduced in R6RS. Amazingly, Scheme programs had no reasonable way to report errors before that.

Don't even think about making a `pop` macro and using the pattern `(f (pop a) (pop a) ... (pop a))`; Scheme doesn't have a defined evaluation order for function arguments unlike some other Lisp dialects like ANSI CL.